# Como pegar a última venda de cada cliente

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho uma tabela de clientes:

```
----------------------------------------------------
codigocliente || razao        || cidade   || estado
----------------------------------------------------
0001          || Sup. Mercado || Londrina || PR 
----------------------------------------------------
0002          || Super Pão    || Arapongas|| PR
----------------------------------------------------
0003          || Loja Comer.  || Cambé    || PR
----------------------------------------------------
```

e uma tabela de nota fiscal:

```
----------------------------------------------------
n_nota || valor_nota || dt_emissao || codigocliente
----------------------------------------------------
0001   || 1000,00    || 2021-01-01 || 0001
----------------------------------------------------
0002   || 2500,00    || 2021-02-13 || 0002  
----------------------------------------------------
0003   || 800,00     || 2021-02-27 || 0001
----------------------------------------------------
0004   || 1500,00    || 2021-03-20 || 0003 
----------------------------------------------------
```

```
SELECT
    c.codigocliente, 
    c.razao, 
    c.cidade, 
    c.estado, 
    MAX(nf.dt_emissao),
    nf.valor_nota
FROM clientes c
LEFT JOIN nota_fiscal nf ON nf.codigocliente = c.codigocliente
GROUP BY c.codigocliente;
```

Como pegar o valor da ultima compra referente a ultima data?

Comment: Qual a versão do seu MySQL?

Comment: Versão do banco 10.4.6-MariaDB

Comment: Consegue adicionar os scripts de criação e dados?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/541c882/12

Answer (score -1):

Para fazer isso pode quebrar isso em duas queries.

A primeira vai retornar o n_nota da data mais recente agrupada por cliente:

```
SELECT MAX(n_nota) n_nota 
  FROM nota_fiscal nf1
 GROUP BY codigocliente
```

Dai basta adicionar essa subquery e fazer o `JOIN` de nota_fiscal com essa query, para garantir que pega os dados da nota_fiscal correta:

```
SELECT
    c.codigocliente, 
    c.razao, 
    c.cidade, 
    c.estado, 
    nf.dt_emissao,
    nf.valor_nota
FROM clientes c
LEFT JOIN nota_fiscal nf ON nf.codigocliente = c.codigocliente
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT MAX(n_nota) n_nota 
       FROM nota_fiscal nf1
      GROUP BY codigocliente) AS aux
      ON nf.n_nota = aux.n_nota
GROUP BY c.codigocliente;
```

Repare que, no `SELECT` principal, está pegando diretamente a data e valor, isso porque o último `JOIN` (`nf.n_nota = aux.n_nota`) garante que o registro em "nota_fiscal" é o mais atual, que é o n_nota retornado na subquery.

Pode ver funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/541c882/11

**UPDATE**: após os comentários, ao testar a query acima para trazer os clientes sem venda, ao substituir o `INNER JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN` retorna os dados do cliente, porém não traz corretamene o registro da venda, por causa do `SELECT` que faz o cálculo do `MAX(n_nota)`. Para resolver isso, adicionei mais um nível na query, para o `LEFT JOIN` com "clientes" ser o único `JOIN` no "primeiro nível" da query, assim:

```
SELECT
    c.codigocliente, 
    c.razao, 
    c.cidade, 
    c.estado, 
    nf.dt_emissao,
    nf.valor_nota
FROM clientes c
LEFT JOIN (
  -- dados da nf mais recente
  SELECT codigocliente,
         dt_emissao, 
         valor_nota
   FROM nota_fiscal nf1
  INNER JOIN 
        -- nf mais recente
        (SELECT MAX(n_nota) n_nota 
           FROM nota_fiscal
          GROUP BY codigocliente) AS aux ON nf1.n_nota = aux.n_nota
        ) AS nf ON nf.codigocliente = c.codigocliente
GROUP BY c.codigocliente;
```

Comment: Certo, mas eu preciso que os clientes sem venda apareça nesta consulta também, como fazer?

Comment: basta mudar o INNER JOIN para LEFT JOIN, que vai trazer os registros que existam em clientes em não na subquery, assim com o outro JOIN :)

Comment: Usei o left Join, mas não trouxe o valor correto referente a data.

Comment: então precisa olhar os seus dados, acabei de fazer essa change que te falei, adicionei outro cliente sem venda e retorna, veja aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83c41b/1

Comment: No próprio exemplo que vc me passou, quando uso INNER JOIN me traz o valor da ultima data, quando uso LEFT ele me traz o valor da primeira data,

Comment: edite o script e coloque os dados que tem, eu montei esse baseado no que tem na pergunta e pode estar diferente

Comment: Blz, vou tentando aqui, Obrigado!

Comment: @MarcosVinicius fiz um teste e consegui replicar o problema, fiz uma alteração na query e coloquei da pergunta, veja lá