# Consulta SQL para trazer a ultima ocorrência

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma consulta que realiza filtragem de dados através de códigos, somando os valores existente, só que preciso trazer na coluna "Marcados"", somente a ultima ocorrência de um numero de telefone, Ex:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não posso mexer na estrutura de como gera a consulta, pois gero um relatório padronizado.
o codigo:

```
select
PhoneNumber
,DataContato            = cast(a.contactDate as Date)
,HoraContato            = cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
,Base                   = Count(a.PhoneNumber)
,Marcados = sum(case when StatusCode in('Cod_1, Cod_2, Cod_3, Cod_4') then 1 else 0 end) 

from OdsAspect.dbo.ContactIntraday a
    where 
    cast(contactDate as Date) between '2021-04-01' and '2021-04-11'
    and [Serviceid] IN (274) 
    group by 
        cast(a.contactDate as Date)
        ,cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
        ,AgentId,
        PhoneNumber
    order by 1,2
```

Comment: faz uma subquery que te retorne o max(id) a partir do phonenumber, tem algo muito parecido nessa outra pergunta, veja se ajuda: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/500548/como-pegar-a-%c3%baltima-venda-de-cada-cliente

Comment: Entendi em partes, estou com problema para deixar com este mesmo padrão, pois teria que estar dentro do agrupamento criado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para realizar esta consulta, pense da teoria dos conjuntos em que você já possui um conjunto inicial e precisa selecionar itens específicos desse conjunto. Sugiro duas soluções:

1. Utilizar subconsulta com base no resultado já obtido;
2. Utilizar a cláusula `HAVING`.

### Utilizar subconsulta com base no resultado já obtido;

Para resolver o problema, considerei o resultado da sua consulta como sendo a tabela `resultado` visto que você já possui esse resultado inicial. Posteriormente, mostrarei outra opção de solução utilizando a cláusula `HAVING`.

Situação foi testada no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dcc10/2) e postado códigos e resultados abaixo:

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE resultado(
    [PhoneNumber] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [DataContato] [date] NULL,
    [HoraContato] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [Base] [int] NULL,
    [Marcados] [varchar](1) NULL
)

insert into resultado values (7,'2021-04-01','11:00','1','1')
insert into resultado values (7,'2021-04-01','15:00','1','0')
insert into resultado values (7,'2021-04-01','11:00','1','0')
insert into resultado values ('06','2021-04-01','09:00','1','0')
insert into resultado values ('06','2021-04-01','16:00','1','1')
insert into resultado values ('06','2021-04-06','11:00','1','0')
insert into resultado values ('06','2021-04-06','16:30','1','1')

insert into resultado values ('83','2021-04-01','11:00','1','1')
insert into resultado values ('83','2021-04-01','13:00','1','0')
insert into resultado values ('83','2021-04-06','13:30','1','0')

insert into resultado values ('1','2021-04-01','11:00','1','1')
insert into resultado values ('1','2021-04-01','11:30','1','0')
insert into resultado values ('1','2021-04-06','12:30','1','0')
```

**Query 1**:

```
With resultado_agrupado AS
    (
       select * from resultado
    )

    Select ra.*
      from resultado_agrupado ra
      where cast(cast(ra.DataContato as varchar) + ' ' + ra.HoraContato+':00' as datetime) = 
        (   Select max(cast(cast(ra2.DataContato as varchar) + ' ' + ra2.HoraContato+':00' as datetime)) dataContato_Ultimo
              from resultado_agrupado ra2
             where ra2.PhoneNumber = ra.PhoneNumber 
        )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dcc10/2/0)**:

| PhoneNumber | DataContato | HoraContato | Base | Marcados |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 06 | 2021-04-06 | 16:30 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-04-06 | 12:30 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-04-01 | 15:00 | 1 | 0 |
| 83 | 2021-04-06 | 13:30 | 1 | 0 |

Usei o trecho para abstrair a complexidade da sua consulta inical

```
With resultado_agrupado AS
    (
       select * from resultado
    )
```

Substituindo o `select * from resultado` pela sua consulta, ficaria:

```
With resultado_agrupado AS
    (
       select
        PhoneNumber
        ,DataContato            = cast(a.contactDate as Date)
        ,HoraContato            = cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
        ,Base                   = Count(a.PhoneNumber)
        ,Marcados = sum(case when StatusCode in('Cod_1, Cod_2, Cod_3, Cod_4') then 1 else 0 end) 

        from OdsAspect.dbo.ContactIntraday a
            where 
            cast(contactDate as Date) between '2021-04-01' and '2021-04-11'
            and [Serviceid] IN (274) 
            group by 
                cast(a.contactDate as Date)
                ,cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
                ,AgentId,
                PhoneNumber
    )
```

### Utilizar a cláusula `HAVING`

Você utiliza o `having` para restringir registros após o processamento do `GROUP BY`.

Observe que é necessário que o campo utilizado no `having` esteja presente também no `group by`, por esse motivo, incluí o campo `contactDate` como último critério do `group by`. Caso sua consulta não possa incluir o campo `contactDate` no `group by` você precisará fazer os `casts` necessários para obter as informações equivalentes na consulta principal após o having e na subconsulta conforme necessário, colocarei um exemplo com `casts` no final desta resposta.

Veja como ficaria sua consulta com a utilização do `HAVING`:

```
--Se tivesse o contactDate no Group By        

select
PhoneNumber
,DataContato            = cast(a.contactDate as Date)
,HoraContato            = cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
,Base                   = Count(a.PhoneNumber)
,Marcados
from ContactIntraday a
    where 
    cast(contactDate as Date) between '2021-04-01' and '2021-04-11'
    and [Serviceid] IN (274) 
    group by 
        cast(a.contactDate as Date)
        ,cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
        ,AgentId,
        ,PhoneNumber
        ,Marcados
        ,contactDate
    having contactDate = (select max(a2.contactDate) from ContactIntraday a2 where a2.PhoneNumber = a.PhoneNumber)
    order by 1,2
```

**Having sem acrescentar `contactDate` e usando `casts`**

```
    select
    PhoneNumber
    ,DataContato            = cast(a.contactDate as Date)
    ,HoraContato            = cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
    ,Base                   = Count(a.PhoneNumber)
    ,Marcados
    from ContactIntraday a
        where 
        cast(contactDate as Date) between '2021-04-01' and '2021-04-11'
        and [Serviceid] IN (274) 
        group by 
            cast(a.contactDate as Date)
            ,cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5))
            ,AgentId
            ,PhoneNumber
            ,Marcados
        having cast(cast(a.contactDate as Date) as varchar) +' '+ cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5)) = 
        (
            select max(
                   cast(cast(cast(a2.contactDate as Date) as varchar) + ' ' + cast(left(cast(dateadd(minute,(datediff(minute,0,a2.ContactDate)/30)*30,0)  as time),5) as varchar(5)) as datetime))
               from ContactIntraday a2 where a2.PhoneNumber = a.PhoneNumber
        )
        order by 1,2
```

Para testar o `having` com a tabela `resultado` proposta, ficaria assim:

```
    Select PhoneNumber, DataContato,    HoraContato,    Base,   Marcados
      from resultado r
      group by PhoneNumber, DataContato,    HoraContato,    Base,   Marcados
      having Cast(cast(DataContato as varchar) + ' ' + HoraContato as datetime) = 
      (
          Select Max(Cast(cast(DataContato as varchar) + ' ' + HoraContato as datetime)) 
             from resultado r2
             where r2.PhoneNumber = r.PhoneNumber
       )
```

Answer (score -2):

Pelo que eu entendi...
Você pode tentar trazer a coluna 'Marcados' usando uma subquerie que traz o valor da maior data/hora do numero de telefone.
Uma ideia que você pode tentar

Algo tipo:

```
marcado = 
 select 'sua_coluna' from OdsAspect.dbo.ContactIntraday a 
Where PhoneNumber = 'seu_numero' and a.contactDate = (select max(a.contactDate) from from OdsAspect.dbo.ContactIntraday a Where PhoneNumber = 'seu_numero' )
```